# change layout in excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel sheet:

[image]

The sheet contains the first name, last name, city, address, etc of many people.

```
     A     |     B         |      C         |         D
   Name    |    city       |    state       |       phone
   name2   |    city       |    state       |       phone
   name3   |    dsfg       |     sdgd       |       sdgsdf
   name4   |    asdf       |    sdfd        |       sdfsdf
```

I want to print something like this:

```
name               name2         name3         name4
city               city          city          city
state              state         state         state
phone              phone         phone         phone
```

I want to print this type label in Invitational card.

Comment: +1 for good clear question. I would consider using a pivot table on a different worksheet to make this change. Then print that worksheet.

Comment: thanks @Dave, sorrry but I cant understand about your solution..

Comment: IMO, it may be easier to use the [Word Mail Merge](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) feature using this worksheet as the the data source.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for "Paste / Transpose":

- Select the cells containing the headings and data you want to transpose.
- Click Copy or press **Ctrl + C**.
- Click in a blank cell on the spreadsheet. This cell will be the top, left corner of the new table of data.
- Click the down arrow on the **Paste** button and select **Paste Special** from the drop-down menu.
- On the Paste Special dialog box, select the **Transpose** check box so there is a check mark in the box and click OK.
  The rows become the columns and the columns become the rows. The original set of data still exists. You can select those cells and delete the headings and data, if desired.

[image]

Comment: yes but is too hard for 1000+ label..

Comment: It is not if you make it at ones: select the whole area (1000+ Label), Ctrl+C, go to empty piece of sheet, Ctrl+V - ready